# Is it possible to filter a BCS list using a site's name?

Tags: site-template, bcs, filter

I'm running SharePoint Foundation and copying a site template per project.  I would like to filter the BCS list in my template using the site name.

Is there a possible method?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah there is, I'm actually filtering BCS lists based upon a property in the site's propertybag, but you can really use any variable you want.

What you basically want to do is use the .NET class option for BCS. Instead of getting results directly out of SQL Server, get them via a .NET class. In the methods used, you can use your SPContext to figure out which site called the method and provide extra filtering instead. I have a brief description up on my blog here: http://blog.repsaj.nl/?p=170, sorry there's no copy/paste code snippets, I can't share that code because it's rights protected. But with some tutorials on using .NET classes for BCS, you'll get there I'm sure.